Error integrating Azure DevOps Classic Pipeline with SonarCloud: Java version issue
I am encountering an issue while attempting to integrate an Azure DevOps classic pipeline with SonarCloud for a Java project that utilizes Maven for package management.
I initially tested this SonarCloud integration using Jenkins, where it appeared to be a Java version issue. However, even after upgrading the Java version on the server and updating certain SonarQube plugins, the error persists. Consequently, I decided to switch to Azure DevOps, but I am still encountering the same issue.
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] petclinic_api 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT ....................... FAILURE [  5.253 s]
[INFO] dto 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT ................................. SUCCESS [  9.515 s]
[INFO] exception 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT ........................... SUCCESS [  0.200 s]
[INFO] petclinic-service-internal 2018.9-RELEASE .......... SUCCESS [ 39.459 s]
[INFO] petclinic-service-external 2018.9-RELEASE .......... SUCCESS [  5.430 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.11.0.3922:sonar
(default-cli) on project my-project-name: The plugin [python] does not support Java 11.0.22: 
org/sonar/plugins/python/PythonPlugin has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime
(class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0 -> [Help 1]

Below are the main configurations in the pipeline:
Classic Pipeline Name: Maven with SonarCloud
Agent: Azure Pipelines (ubuntu-latest)
Scanner: Use standalone scanner
Mode: Manual provide configuration
Maven goals and options: package  -e  -Dmaven.test.skip=true
Code analysis: Run SonarQube or SonarCloud analysis (use latest version)
JDK version: Default

main pom.yaml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>com.petclinic</groupId>
   <artifactId>petclinic_service</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <packaging>pom</packaging>
   <name>petclinic_api</name>
   <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
   <modules>
      <module>dto</module>
      <module>exception</module>
      <module>petclinic-saas</module>
      <module>petclinic-api</module>
   </modules>
</project>

Following steps have been taken:

I upgraded the Java version on the server and updated certain SonarQube plugins. I was expecting these changes to resolve the compatibility issue with SonarCloud.
Upgraded the Jenkins version as well but no change in the response.
Changed the JDK version to 17, then I received the following error

[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] petclinic_api 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT ....................... SUCCESS [  0.005 s]
[INFO] dto 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT ................................. SUCCESS [  9.315 s]
[INFO] exception 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT ........................... SUCCESS [  0.219 s]
[INFO] petclinic-service-internal 2018.9-RELEASE .......... FAILURE [ 18.852 s]
[INFO] petclinic-service-external 2018.9-RELEASE .......... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile)
on project petclinic-saas: Fatal error compiling: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class lombok.javac.apt.LombokProcessor
(in unnamed module @0x1667a6f7) cannot access class
com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export
com.sun.tools.javac.processing to unnamed module @0x1667a6f7 -> [Help 1]

Could someone provide guidance or assistance in resolving this issue? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Can you check the version of the dependency org.projectlombok in your pom.xml file?

@KevinLu-MSFT I'm using 1.18.10. It seems I need to switch to at least 1.18.22 right?

Yes. Old versions are not compatible with Java 17. You need to upgrade the org.projectlombok to a higher version. I test to use Java 17 and  org.projectlombok 1.18.28`. It can work as expected. I have added an answer to share the info. You can try it.

@KevinLu-MSFT Switched to 1.18.28 and it fixed the issue. Thank you for the guidance!!

I have already tried that, but unfortunately, I don't have enough reputation to cast a vote.

Just accepted it. Thank you for the guidance, but I'm not able to cast a vote due to the above reason.

No Problem. Thank you for your recognition.


Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.11.0.3922:sonar
(default-cli) on project my-project-name: The plugin [python] does not support Java 11.0.22

For this issue, this means that you need to upgrade your java version.

Fatal error compiling: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class lombok.javac.apt.LombokProcessor
(in unnamed module @0x1667a6f7) cannot access class..

After you upgrade Java version to 17, the cause of this issue is that the dependency org.projectlombok version is not compatible with Java version.
I can reproduce the same issue when using version 1.18.10.

To solve this issue, you need to upgrade the version of dependency org.projectlombok(e.g. version 1.18.28).
For example:
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.28</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

Result:

For more detailed info, you can refer to this ticket: Make Lombok compatible with JDK
